# deep search level 3 in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have data this

```cs
[
  {
    "_id": "5f68c2b904f588d426ec8ce2",
    "name": "name 1",
    "code": "code 1",
    "district": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "district 1",
        "wards": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "ward 1"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "ward 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "district 2",
        "wards": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "ward 3"
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "ward 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f68c2b904f588d426ec8ce8",
    "name": "name 2",
    "code": "code 2",
    "district": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "district 3",
        "wards": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "ward 5"
          },
          {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "ward 6"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "district 4",
        "wards": [
          {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "ward 7"
          },
          {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "ward 8"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i using code mongoose in nodejs, now i want search sub data in level 3 width where is

```
{
  "_id": "5f68c2b904f588d426ec8ce2",
  "district.id":"1"
}
```

i need code nodejs result data is array

```
 [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ward 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "ward 2"
      }
    ]
```

please help me ? thanks all support me

i need code nodejs result data is array

```
 [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ward 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "ward 2"
      }
    ]
```

please help me ? thanks all support me

Comment: I think there's a problem with your sample data, as it seems that you have an object with an array inside, and you want to find a specific item by id? I don't see where the third level comes from, unless you've accidentally missed out the outermost level.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired results by leveraging the mongodb [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method which is [supported in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate()) too. Try this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": "5f68c2b904f588d426ec8ce2",
      "district.id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$district"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "district.id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$district.wards"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$district.wards"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a [working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9VEn5ZGuZ1Z).

**Explanation**

Each stage of the aggregate method is called a pipeline and takes each document one at a time and essentially filters them through your different pipeline stages.

1. `$match`: - find the documents that match your `{"_id": "5f68c2b904f588d426ec8ce2", "district.id": "1"}` conditions.
2. `$unwind`: - take the matching document and unwind the `district` array which essentially flattens the array into individual objects.
3. `$match`: - now you can match only the object that meets your `"district.id": "1"` condition.
4. `$unwind`: - now unwind the `wards` array into individual objects which will allow you to use them as direct replacements for the top-level of the document.
5. `$replaceRoot`: - step inside the `district` objects and take each `wards` object to act as replacements for the top-level documents.

There may be more efficient pipeline stages but this gives you an insight into how you can combine different stages to filter and transform your documents.